# Firebase AppCheck VS hackers & spammy requests

Tags: firebase, security, token, firebase-app-check

Although I fully understand the use of AppCheck, I still wonder how it can help against spamming request to an API endpoint.
In the scenario of a hacker using OpenBullet or whatever hacker tool to spam thousands of requests per minutes to a specific endpoint (for example, a Signup endpoints to create thousands of fake profiles in a social app):

once the hacker got their hand on the appcheck token from the device, can't they simply attach it to the request's header, and spam all they want the api endpoint that we secured from our backend by checking appcheck token?
I mean, as long as the TTL didn't expire, I guess all their requests will pass the check thus they could use their hacker tool and pretend to come from the untempered app? Or am I missing something?

I guess a solution would be to:
1- forceRefresh the appcheck token on each fetch request from the mobile app
2- expire the received appcheck token programmatically after successful verification from the backend, so that further request would need a new one that can only be generated from the app, thus making it harder for the hacker?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put it in a different way. While AppCheck offers a level of protection to your resources, it does not guarantee 100% protection. The sample you gave is an instance on how it could be bypassed. But what can't be factored out is that AppCheck makes it harder for a malicious actor to roam around your services and consume them on your budget.

Take a look at [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check#how_strong_is_the_security_provided_by) from the documentation. Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68756032/does-firebase-app-check-discard-the-need-for-implementing-security-rules) as it was asked after your question and had a firebaser (Frank) corresponding to it.